# Are there any viable alternatives to Paypal for a small site?

Tags: paypal, online-payment, ecommerce, small-business

I don't want to have the hassle of dealing with credit card or direct payments directly on my website, the volume and amount of transactions don't justify the effort.

I've set up Paypal on the site to allow for payments, but I'm not entirely happy with the experience.

Are there any viable alternatives to Paypal for the small website that will allow me to conduct business without having to handle customer details directly?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have posted the question there too: http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/3458

Comment: To anyone now reading this, the link above no longer leads to the question: "The Answers on Startups site didn't have enough activity during the beta, and has been closed."

Answer (score 6):

I found out about [Google checkout](https://checkout.google.com/seller/what.html?hl=en&gl=GB) today, it looks like it may meet my needs, but I'd still be interested to find out about other options.

Comment: To anyone reading this now, Google Checkout was shutdown in November of 2013. However, the services it offered were rolled into Google Wallet: https://www.google.com/wallet/

Answer (score 5):

While I've never used the service, there's also [Amazon Flexible Payments Services (AFPS)](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/):
*(emphasis below is mine)*

> Amazon Flexible Payments ServiceTM
>   (Amazon FPS) is the first payments
>   service designed from the ground up
>   for developers. It is built on top of
>   Amazon’s reliable and scalable
>   payments infrastructure and provides
>   developers with a convenient way to
>   charge Amazon’s tens of millions of
>   customers (with their permission, of
>   course!). **Amazon customers can pay
>   using the same login credentials,
>   shipping address and payment
>   information they already have on file
>   with Amazon.** [...]

Considering Amazon.com is an e-commerce heavyweight, it might be worth a look.